# spring framework role in mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

It's a question about Spring Framework and its architecture. I have read a lot about Spring in the middle-tier or in the layer scheme. But, I need to know which is the role of this framework inside the MVC pattern.

I must clarify I'm not talking about Spring MVC, but about the entire framework.

For example:

- View: JSP, JSF, etc...
- Controller: Servlets, Spring?, etc...
- Model: Spring?, Hibernate, JPA, etc...

I don´t know where can I locate this framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring Framework (`context`, `core`, `aop`, `tx`, `jdbc`) for inversion of control, transactions, aspect oriented programming, JDBC support you definitely use it in `M`.

If you use Spring MVC for your web controllers you definitely use it in `C`.

If you use Spring jsp tags, you also use it in your `V`.

Comment: So Spring is able to give solutions for all parts of an application. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Below url would be helpful to you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_overview.htm